# For $f, g \in K[t]$, $f \neq g$ implies $f_K \neq g_K$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

> Consider an infinite field $K$. For $f, g \in K[t]$, show that $f \neq
>  g$ implies $f_K \neq g_K$, where $f_K, g_K: K \rightarrow K$ denote
>   the usual polynomial functions.

My attempt:
By Euclidean Algorithm, there exist unique $q, r \in K[t]$ such that $$f=qg+r$$ where we have assumed $deg(f) \geq deg(g)$ and $deg(r)<deg(g)$. Then for any $x \in K$, $$f_K(x)=q_K(x)g_K(x)+r_K(x)$$
and now I am stuck. I don't see the significance of 'infinite' in the proof. I also think of using the roots of $f$ and $g$, but the existence of roots is not guaranteed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Consider $f-g$ and remember that a polynomial of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ roots.

Comment: For finite fields this isn't true, consider the $\mathbb{F}_2$ field and polynomials $P_1(t) = t$ and $P_2(t) = t^2$. These two are different polynomials (i.e. different elements of $\mathbb{F}_2[t]$, but they both represent identity function $\mathrm{id}_K = \{\langle0,0\rangle,\langle1,1\rangle\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Derek Holt hinted, you should consider the polynomial $h=f-g$. By hypothesis $h\ne 0$. Then consider the associated polynomial function of $h$, denoted here by $h_K$. Suppose the contrary that $h_K=0$, that is, $h_K(a)=0$ for all $a\in K$. This means that all elements of $K$ are roots of $h$. But over a field a polynomial can't have more (distinct) roots than its degree, a contradiction. (Here is where you use that $K$ is infinite.)